# Extracting existential from proxy

Tags: haskell, existential-type

Is it possible to write `extractT`?

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}
import Data.Proxy

data T = forall t. Show t => T (Proxy t)

extractT :: Proxy T -> T
extractT p = ...
```

I have tried

```
extractT p = T $ p >>= \(T t) -> t
```

but it does not work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, it is not possible (aside from “trivial” implementations like [this one by melpomene](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53342370/465378) that ignore the argument entirely).

A value of type `Proxy a` carries no more information at runtime than `()` does, which is to say it doesn’t carry any information at all. This is true no matter what `a` is.

Your type `T` carries more information than just `()` at runtime: it carries a `Show` method dictionary for some type around with it. This dictionary isn’t very useful, since by the time the existential is unpacked, you don’t have any way to obtain a value of type `t` to use `show` on, but the information is technically there.

Since constructing a `T` requires supplying a typeclass dictionary, but the dictionary (nor any means to obtain it) does not exist inside `Proxy T`, and there is not any static information about which type the dictionary should be for, it is impossible to obtain the dictionary necessary to construct a `T`. Put another way, constructing a value of type `Proxy T` does not pick a `t`—there is no type “inside” the `T` in `Proxy T`—since `Proxy` only carries around type-level information, but the `t` inside the `T` type only exists at the value level.

Comment: Thanks, now I understand it

Answer (score 3):

```
extractT :: Proxy T -> T
extractT _ = T (Proxy :: Proxy ())
```

I'm not sure how useful this is (or how it is "extracting" anything), but it has the required type signature.

Comment: I want to have the same type inside `Proxy T` and in `T`, for example `p = Proxy :: Proxy (T (Proxy :: Proxy String))` and i want get `extractT p = T (Proxy :: Proxy String)`

Comment: @ПьерБезухов There is no type inside `Proxy T`.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. From the [documentation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Proxy.html):

> `Proxy` is a type that holds no data

There is nothing you can extract from a `Proxy` value besides its type. And the type `Proxy T` doesn't say anything about the type inside the `T` value, because there is *no* `T` value inside.